# What is the solution for following issue if The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, view

I'm getting following error:

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()
> on the child's parent first.

when I tried to show image in alertdialogue by clicking on particular image, the image has been fetched from Mysql and then populated in ListView.

Here is my code:

```
Picasso.get()
        .load("http://111.111.11.1/api/images/" + model.getImage())
        .into(imageView);
Picasso.get()
        .load("http://111.111.11.1/api/images/" + model.getCheckin_pic())
        .into(checkInPic);
Picasso.get()
        .load("http://111.111.11.1/api/images/" + model.getCheckout_pic())
        .into(checkOutPic);



textView_id.setText(String.valueOf(model.getId()));
textView_name.setText(model.getName());
textView_cnic.setText(model.getCnic());
textView_address.setText(model.getAddress());
textView_email.setText(model.getEmail());
textView_guardian.setText(model.getGuardian());

checkInPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       
          //here trying tp display image in alert dialogue


        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).
                      
                        setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).
                        setView(checkInPic);
        builder.create().show();

    }
```

I know this question has been asked before, but it didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work cuz your dialog has a different view entirely. So the error means: hey, I have a parent already(which is in your activity view), why are you giving me to another parent(alertDialog view).

What to do:

1. create a custom layout that has imageView for the dialog,
2. inflate the layout, pass the image URL to the dialog,
3. load the image on the imageview inside the custom dialog by using Picasso(same way u did bf in ur activity)

Hope I pointed u in the right path

Comment: Its late over here(2am), I'll write the codes during the day. If your okay with it